# Azure Service Bus message time to live setting

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I would like to ask what is the best practice for **Azure Service Bus** message **TTL (time to live)** option - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration.

We use Azure Service Bus to import data from one system to another, amount of records is a couple of millions.

Briefly saying, this option tells ASB how much time a message can stay in a queue or a topic before it moved to dead letter queue(if it is configured) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#moving-messages-to-the-dlq.

Even so, I cannot find how TTL value impacts on ASB throughput and performance. *What is difference between 5 minutes, 1 hour and 20 hours set for TTL in terms of ASB queue/topic performance?*

Thank you in advance

Comment: **"What is difference between 5 minutes, 1 hour and 20 hours set for TTL in terms of ASB queue/topic performance?"** That's impossible to assess without knowing the architecture of the applications using the Service Bus.

Comment: You are right. I will add a couple of notes about our needs and what for we use ASB

Comment: TTL should not be abused. Use a reasonable max value. Remember, Azure Service Bus is a messaging service, not a storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to live property is used to set the expiration time window for messages in Service Bus.

Based the time configured for TTL, the messages either moved to dead-letter or lost from the Queue. The usage of this property may differ based on the use cases.

For example, if I am sure that my system will not go down and will pick the messages as soon as it is en-queued, I will configure the TTL to very minimal time window say 1 minute (helps to verify the system is working fine by monitoring the dead-letter length of the Queue). If my system is not reliable or the system runs only once a day to process the messages, then I should have a higher value for this property, so that the messages will be available in the Queue for a longer time, letting the system to process.

Coming to the performance, there will not be much lack in the performance in the Queue due to the higher values of TTL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If it does not impact performance and we will not have much lack, we can use higher value than we have right now.